# obtaining number of nodes, number of codes and available RAM for tuning

Tags: apache-spark, slurm, sparklyr

I am trying **to tune my HPC cluster** (I use Sparklyr) and I try to collect some important specs specified by http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/:

> To hopefully make all of this a little more concrete, here’s a worked
>   example of configuring a Spark app to use as much of the cluster as
>   possible: Imagine a cluster with six nodes running NodeManagers, each
>   equipped with 16 cores and 64GB of memory.

namely:

- number of nodes
- number of cores
- disk space and RAM

I know how to use `sinfo -n -l` but I see too many cores and I cannot easily get this information. Is there a simpler way to know the overall specs of my cluster?

Ultimately, I am trying to find some reasonable parameters for
`--num-executors` `--executor-cores` and `--executor-memory`

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: OK removed. can you upvote again~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of nodes:

```
sinfo -O "nodes" --noheader
```

Number of cores: Slurm's "cores" are, by default, the number of cores **per socket**, not the total number of cores available on the node. Somewhat confusingly, in Slurm, cpus = cores * sockets (thus, a two-processor, 6-cores machine would have 2 sockets, 6 cores and 12 cpus).

Number of cores (=cpus in Slurm), disk space and RAM are more tricky to get, as it might be different on different nodes. The following returns an easy-to-parse list:

```
sinfo -N -O "nodehost,disk,memory,cpus" --noheader
```

If all nodes that are the same, we can get the info from the first row of sinfo:

Number of cores (=Slurm cpus) per node:

```
sinfo -N -O "cpus" --noheader | head -1
```

RAM per node:

```
sinfo -N -O "memory" --noheader | head -1
```

disk space per node:

```
sinfo -N -O "disk" --noheader | head -1
```

Comment: great! you are right not all the nodes have the same RAM/specs.. how does that affect your answer?

Comment: @Noobie: see my edit; though, if nodes differ, you should optimize your spark execution based on the parameters of nodes you actually got for your job (thus, after the job has started). It requires some scripting...

Comment: Oddly enough, I when I type `sinfo -N -l` I see a number of CPUs that is bigger than the number of cores I see by typing `sinfo -N -O "nodehost,disk,memory,cores" --noheader`. what does that mean??